# App occasionally gets SIGKILL, seems to be stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:

Tags: objective-c, macos

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", [temp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
DLog(@"urlString:%@",urlString); //http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Kebon%20Jeruk,Jakarta&output=csv
NSURL * Url= [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; //http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Kebon%20Jeruk,Jakarta&output=csv
// Getting a SIGKILL on the next line; the program aborts
NSString * result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:Url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
DLog(@"Result:%@",result);
```

I have no idea why my Mac app is getting SIGKILL; it only happens once in a while.

I checked and checked and checked, nothing makes sense. All the arguments that I send on that line are fine.

Comment: Open instrument and check if you have severe leaks any where around this code.

Comment: By SIGKILL, do you mean an NSException?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a new project, and after changing the DLogs (wouldn't compile with these) to NSLogs it worked fine.

Comment: It only fails once in a while. Worst come to worst I can use try catch. However, I wonder why sigkill is sent in the first place.

Comment: What platform? iOS or Mac OS?

Comment: I mean it's MacOs Sorry. Will delete last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:Url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]
```

TryThis instead.

Comment: Someone else downvoted you, but it's not clear. What's the difference between what you wrote and the original?

Comment: Its encoding type,There are several encoding types that iphone supports.I dont know why someone downvoted..but I just want  to u to go with alternative approach..try it and let me know whether it works?

Comment: Hmmm... Let me check yea that may be the issue. Good answer actually. Perhaps you should add that in the answer. I temporarily set this as the answer.